# Is there a grammatical term for two "conditional" subordinate clauses being combined with "and"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

First off, sorry if my question is confusing. Or just plain wrong for what I am actually asking. But I am confused. I'm trying to figure out why there are no commas in two specific sentences. I don't think these sentences are wrong, but I want to understand why they are right. I am looking for a rule, but I lack the terminology to search for a rule.

Here are the sentences:

> **Because the topic covers several issues and because I was already working on one of the sub-topics for another article**, I thought I’d answer the question in an article rather than in the comment section.

and

> I’m going to focus on adverbial clauses **since they’re usually the ones that cause the most problems and because the example in the reader’s question uses an adverbial clause**.

They are both taken from this article: http://theeditorsblog.net/2014/07/30/commas-with-subordinate-clauses-a-readers-question/

The parts that, for some reason or other, confound me are in bold. Both are subordinate/dependent clauses, and both begin with a subordinate conjunction. At least, I believe that is the case. 
But what do they turn into when the construction is done like the above? A "compound subordinate clause"? And why would there be a small voice in my head, asking me why there is no comma before the "and" in the bold parts of my quotes?

Additionally, would the same grammatical "state" (yes, I am obviously lacking terminology, I apologize) still apply if, in the first quote, the subordinate conjunction was not repeated? As in:

> **Because the topic covers several issues and I was already working on one of the sub-topics for another article**, I thought I’d answer the question in an article rather than in the comment section.

And again I feel like there should be a comma here between "issues" and "and".

Someone please help me out here.

Thank you.

Comment: Deleting the second 'because' in your third example implies that there is a two-part reason rather than two reasons (though this may often boil down to the same thing). I'd say that the comma before 'and' is rulewise optional, but in kindness-to-readers terms, essential.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify: Are you talking about the comma before 'and' only in the third example or in all examples?

Comment: All; also. a comma before 'since' is probably best if you add one before 'and'  in your second example. Read them out and see where pauses sound natural. Though there _are_ useful rules, there's also a lot more flexibility than many people imagine.

Comment: Thanks. But... wouldn't the comma there be in "defiance" of the "no-comma before subordinate clauses if they come after the independent clause" rule?

Comment: Yes. But, [like @rhetorician and Oscar Wilde](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367305/comma-placement-before-and-followed-by-a-dependent-clause), I consider that 'rule' a guideline. 'We need to give commas a little breathing space' is a delightful double entendre, though 'we can use commas where a little breathing space is reasonable and no confusion is generated' spells it out more clearly.

Comment: I would suggest this was a case of a writer knowing their purpose and their audience. They could expect most to understand their meaning if the second 'because' was omitted; they chose to know their words specified their meaning precisely at the cost of an extra 'because'.

Comment: Thanks people. I will say that while diving into the deeper grammatical works of the English language, nothing so far has mystified me as much as comma "rules" :)

Answer (score 1):

The *Gregg Reference Manual* 10th edition (2005) mentions this rule in ¶130a:

> Note: When two dependent clauses both modify the main clause that follows, do not use a comma to separate the dependent clauses. Insert a comma only before the main clause. [Example:] "If you send us your resume in advance and you bring in a portfolio showing samples of your work, we will be glad to set up an interview for you during the last week of this month." (Do not insert a comma after *advance*.)